# How to/is there a simple way to stitch together an HDRI image from a google earth street view location?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I'd like to make an HDRI image out of [this spot in Manhattan](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Manhattan,+New+York,+NY/@40.7598575,-73.9772011,3a,89.7y,293.62h,99.8t/data=!3m8!1e1!3m6!1s-ei8uCFpEZKQ%2FWCO6nemVd5I%2FAAAAAAAAAM8%2FaeeYEgL6txsjo-nkOm62_6NXHhd35JRuACLIB!2e4!3e11!6s%2F%2Flh4.googleusercontent.com%2F-ei8uCFpEZKQ%2FWCO6nemVd5I%2FAAAAAAAAAM8%2FaeeYEgL6txsjo-nkOm62_6NXHhd35JRuACLIB%2Fw203-h100-k-no-pi-0-ya302.04465-ro0-fo100%2F!7i8704!8i4352!4m5!3m4!1s0x89c2588f046ee661:0xa0b3281fcecc08c!8m2!3d40.7830603!4d-73.9712488!6m1!1e1). I've been looking for a tool that allows me to create an HDRI map out of a google earth location, but it does not seem possible to do easily, so I think I'll just have to stitch one together using Photoshop. I don't know much about photoshop, so how would I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Just a few minutes after posting this, I found a [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=boxFFl-G47M) explaining the process well and in detail. I really need to learn to wait more than 10 minutes before asking around.